# Menu e submenu com bootstrap

Tags: bootstrap-3

Estou tentando adicionar um subitem abaixo de *about* mas não estou conseguindo. Testei com as tags *ul* e *li*, mas não funcionou.

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-2">
       <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">About</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">Services</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">Contact</a>
                    </li>
       </ul>
</div>
```

Alguma sugestão?

Comment: Dropdowns aninhados: https://vsn4ik.github.io/bootstrap-submenu/

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
    <ul class="nav nav-pills">
...
      <li role="presentation" class="dropdown">
        <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
          Dropdown <span class="caret"></span>
        </a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          <li>SubMenu1</li>
          <li>SubMenu2</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
     ...
    </ul>
```

Mais detalhes olhe: http://getbootstrap.com/components/#nav

Comment: Dessa forma deu certo, obrigado.

Comment: Não há do que... :)

Answer (score 6):

Não sei se é o que você quer, mas aqui deu certo assim:

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-2">
       <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">About</a>
                            <ul>
                                <li><a href="#">Teste</a></li>
                            </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">Services</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">Contact</a>
                    </li>
       </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Dessa forma saiu tudo desconfigurado, mas obrigado pela ajuda :)

Answer (score 2):

Teste com está estrutura:

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
 ...
 <li role="presentation" class="dropdown">
   <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
   Dropdown <span class="caret"></span>
   </a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
     ...
    </ul>
  </li>
...
</ul>
```

Comment: Dessa forma deu certo. Obrigado.

Answer (score 2):

Na documentação mostra o exemplo básico de um `dropdown` na seguinte estrutura:

```
li
  > a 
  > ul
     > li
     > + li's ...
  > /ul
/li
```

Onde `<a>` referencia o menu `<ul>` como ancora.

Para funcionar apenas inclua a classe `dropdown` no `<li>` pai e as classes `dropdown` no atributo `data-toggle` e `dropdown-toggle`
na classe da tag `<a>` e referencie utilizando a classe `dropdown-menu` no `<ul>`, assim:

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-2">
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav">

    <li class="dropdown">

      <a href="#" data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle"> About <span class="caret"></span></a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li><a href="#">Enterprise</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Autor</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Something else</a></li>
      </ul>

    </li>

    <li>
      <a href="#">Services</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">Contact</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Veja funcionando no [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gabrielr47/jdqmhx68/)